# Remove a duplicate documents from results returned by SOLR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have one scenario, in which I am searching a `no pan` string in a documents. In my application, we are sending two query request to SOLR i.e one is with `Exact` query(i.e phrase query) which returns me Exact results and next query is `AND` query. But it happens that the results of `Exact` query are also contains in the `AND` query, so I want to remove that records from `AND` query results. So its possible to remove from SOLR end?

I am using `sunspot gem` and rails.

Answer (score 0):

If your document contains any unique field then use that field in second query as a not in query.

for example if you have id as unique field.
Then from the first query you get those ids

and put in the second query as

```
-id:(123 OR 345)
```

So from the second queries result these will get filtered...

Answer (score 0):

Or simply you can re-formulate the second request to include AND but exclude the exact matches.

The updated second request becomes a negation of the current first request (exclude exact matches) combined with your current second request (via an and operation).